# Angular Strap - alerts doen't work with directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-strap

I wrote directive to show notification in some scope:
But, bootstrap strap(http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/alerts) alert service doesn't add alerts to my directive container, why?

```
  app.directive("notification", function ($alert, $rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<div></div>',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var id = "#alerts-container" + getRandomId();
                element.attr("id", id);
                scope.$on('notificationEvent', function (event, alertArg) {
                    var alert = angular.extend(alertArg, {container: id});
                    console.log(alert);
                    $alert(alert);
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

Page:

```
<notification>
</notification>
```

All events are handled, no errors while notificationEvent is running, but my notification container is empty always. Could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: So are you using angular-strap or bootstrap ui for angular ?

Comment: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/alerts

Comment: Try injecting the $alert  app.directive("notification",['$alert', function ($alert, $rootScope) { }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you set just id instead of selector ('#' + id).

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake: id - is incorrect;
attr('id', '#id') - #...